# Finding administrative boundaries in Guinea using OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries

I am trying to map the quarters (neighborhoods) in the city of Conakry, Guinea.

As far as I can find, OMS contains information on the location of each quarter, and displays this with a point in the center of each quarter.

I need the boundaries of each quarter. I have checked www.gadm.org, they have boundaries up to the point of commune (sub-prefecture), which is one level above quarter.

My question is, is this information in OSM, and did I miss it (no purple lines), if not, is there an other way to find it?

Comment: As you mention it, the suburbs are only located as nodes within the OSM database. This was done by someone from Switzerland, so he may not have had local knowledge to add the exact borders. You might look for local governmental information about borders if you need them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use overpass-turbo to get boundaries from OSM: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1lX . But it looks like there is nothing in Guinea.

Comment: Late update: In 2015, the requested boundaries have been added to Openstreetmap by the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download any OSM data through QGIS (2.14+) easily.

Open the Download Data tool under Geoprocessing -> OpenStreetMap and set up your extent using a layer, the map canvas, or manual coordinates. Pick an output file.

[image: download data]

Hit OK. Wait for the tool to run, and close the tool.

Open the Import Data from XML tool under the same menu as the Download Data tool.

Select your .osm file you just created, and set the other parameters as you will. Leaving them default works.

[image: it's the xml thing]

Click OK. Sometimes it will give an error; generally it still actually worked.

Open the third tool in the Geoprocessing -> OpenStreetMap menu. Select Polygons and click Load From DB:

[image: load from db]

You should be greeted with a list of features available. Select the ones you want, and make sure you select Not Null next to that as well, otherwise it will load every polygon in the area. If there are no features, an actual error has occurred, and you will need to redownload and hope for the best.

You should now have the boundaries you were looking for.

Comment: While this basically answers the question of how to download the data, the asker noted that the data was **NOT** present at the time of asking. In the meantime, he seems to have found the data elsewhere and added it to Openstreetmap GPX traces himself.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but this question was linked to a related question, so I added an answer in case someone else comes looking for this sort of problem again

Comment: I think your answer fits better to that other question.

Comment: Yeah, but it was removed from the other one because that question was a duplicate of this.